# jQuery counter function for Numbers not animating after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a socket-io connection to a server, which works well. The server sends new data to the script, once things change. Through this trigger, I call a function, to update things on the page.

```js
let obj = {
    values: {
        "number1": 200,
        "number2": 300
    }
}

Object.entries(obj.values).forEach(entry => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    // Update corresponding ID
    if (value) {
        animateNumbers($('#' + key + "_value"), value);
    }
});

// Function for animating numbers
function animateNumbers(elm, value) {
    let nr = elm.text();
    let dcPlaces;
    let nrIsFloat = false;

    // Determine the type of Number
    if (!isNaN(nr) && nr.toString().indexOf('.') != -1) {
        nrIsFloat = true;
        dcPlaces = nr.split('.');
        dcPlaces = dcPlaces.length > 1 ? dcPlaces[1].length : 0;
    }

    elm.prop('Counter', nr).animate({
        Counter: value
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "swing",
        step: function (now) {
            // Check added for decimal number
            elm.text(nrIsFloat ? now.toFixed(dcPlaces) : Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
    console.log(`Present Number: ${nr} - New Number: ${value}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="number1_value"></span><br/>
<span id="number2_value"></span><br/>
```

The problem after some time is, that the numbers are not animated anymore, but I can see, that the connection to the server is still present. Further I am displaying the changes via the console and the new values arrive through the console.

If I remove all the animation things, the numbers are displayed in-time.

Can someone help, to find out, why the animation "stops"?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] it to make a [mcve] with input and expected output

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: *only working the first time a number changes* - how do you call the function?  Do you refresh/reload/add html to your page?  As above, make sure you include *all* the relevant details (eg HTML) so we can *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a reproducible snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: No, i am not able to do that, because it stops randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a maybe.

This is happening because you are animating according to the number1 and number2 values. Once the animation is complete the number1 and number2 is 200 and 300, and so there is nothing to animate to, but if you (the server) send new values like:

```
obj = {
        values: {
            "number1": 500000000000,
            "number2": 600000000000
        }
    }

    Object.entries(obj.values).forEach(entry => {
        const [key, value] = entry;
        // Update corresponding ID
        if (value) {
            animateNumbers($('#' + key + "_value"), value);
        }
    });
```

the animation will start again, and then send the next one:

```
obj = {
        values: {
            "number1": 5000000001,
            "number2": 6000000000
        }
    }

    Object.entries(obj.values).forEach(entry => {
        const [key, value] = entry;
        // Update corresponding ID
        if (value) {
            animateNumbers($('#' + key + "_value"), value);
        }
    });
```

animation will start again.

Comment: That's correct but after some time, they stop to be animated and I don't know why.